# Error converting text to lowercase with tm_map(..., tolower)

Tags: r, tm, lowercase, term-document-matrix

I tried using the `tm_map`. It gave the following error. How can I get around this?

```
 require(tm)
 byword<-tm_map(byword, tolower)

Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Comment: What package is `tm_map` from? This seems to be dependent on some non-base package. Please consider including `library` statement for completeness.

Comment: @DanielKrizian : `tm_map()` is from `tm` package, and `tolower()` is from `base`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use the base R function `tolower()`:

```
tolower(c("THE quick BROWN fox"))
# [1] "the quick brown fox"
```

Comment: Thanks. But any insight as to why I got that error? I might need to use other tm_map applications!

Comment: The help file for `tm_map` (in the package `tm`) shows a list of usable transformation functions and `tolower` is not one of them. The transformations appear to be S3 methods that operate on objects of class 'Corpus'. So you can't use just any function with `tm_map`.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640188/error-converting-text-to-lowercase-with-tm-map-tolower/17864484?noredirect=1#comment40198625_17864484) to a more detailed answer here: you have to wrap `tolower` inside of `content_transformer` not to screw up the `VCorpus` object -- something like:

```
> library(tm)
> data('crude')
> crude[[1]]$content
[1] "Diamond Shamrock Corp said that\neffective today it had cut its contract prices for crude oil by\n1.50 dlrs a barrel.\n    The reduction brings its posted price for West Texas\nIntermediate to 16.00 dlrs a barrel, the copany said.\n    \"The price reduction today was made in the light of falling\noil product prices and a weak crude oil market,\" a company\nspokeswoman said.\n    Diamond is the latest in a line of U.S. oil companies that\nhave cut its contract, or posted, prices over the last two days\nciting weak oil markets.\n Reuter"
> tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))[[1]]$content
[1] "diamond shamrock corp said that\neffective today it had cut its contract prices for crude oil by\n1.50 dlrs a barrel.\n    the reduction brings its posted price for west texas\nintermediate to 16.00 dlrs a barrel, the copany said.\n    \"the price reduction today was made in the light of falling\noil product prices and a weak crude oil market,\" a company\nspokeswoman said.\n    diamond is the latest in a line of u.s. oil companies that\nhave cut its contract, or posted, prices over the last two days\nciting weak oil markets.\n reuter"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(byword))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus , tolower)

print(myCorpus[[1]])
```

Comment: You should wrap `tolower` inside of `content_transformer` not to screw up the `VCorpus` object, like: `tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))`

Comment: @daroczig: Please make that an answer!

Comment: @smci thanks for the idea, I've just submitted the above comment as a new answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

using tolower in this way has an undesirable side effect: if you try to create a term document matrix out of the corpus later, it will fail. This is because of a recent change in tm that cannot handle the return type of tolower. Instead, use:

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
```