# FUN-error after running 'tolower' while making Twitter wordcloud

Tags: r, twitter, tm

Trying to create wordcloud from twitter data, but get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[72L]], ...) : 
  invalid input '������������❤������������ "@xxx:bla, bla, bla... http://t.co/56Fb78aTSC"' in 'utf8towcs'
```

This error appears after running the     "mytwittersearch_corpus<-
  tm_map(mytwittersearch_corpus, tolower)"  code

```
mytwittersearch_list <-sapply(mytwittersearch, function(x) x$getText())

mytwittersearch_corpus <-Corpus(VectorSource(mytwittersearch_corpus_list))
mytwittersearch_corpus<-tm_map(mytwittersearch_corpus, tolower)
mytwittersearch_corpus<-tm_map( mytwittersearch_corpus, removePunctuation)
mytwittersearch_corpus <-tm_map(mytwittersearch_corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords()))
```

I read on other pages this may be due to R having difficulty processing symbols, emoticons and letters in non-English languages, but this appears not to be the problem with the "error tweets" that R has issues with. I did run the codes:

```
mytwittersearch_corpus <- tm_map(mytwittersearch_corpus, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte"))
mytwittersearch_corpus<- tm_map(mytwittersearch_corpus, content_transformer(function(x)    iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "bytes")))
```

These do not help. I also get that it can't find function `content_transformer` even though the `tm-package` is checked off and running.

I'm running this on OS X 10.6.8 and using the latest  RStudio.

Comment: Maybe you wanna try the tolower function from the stringi package: `tm_map(mytwittersearch_corpus, content_transformer(stringi::stri_trans_tolower))`.

Comment: `content_transformer` is relatively new. You may need to update the package.  What is `packageVersion("tm")`?

Comment: As Richard says, it is probably more important to post the version of R and of the packages that are loaded. The `sessionInfo()` function is the easiest way to gather and present that information.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Richard! I tried to run the code, but unfortunately I get the same message. I will try to update the tm package though. Could the absence of content_transformer explain the error, maybe?

Comment: See if you get the same sort of error with a reduced version of `mytwittersearch`, perhaps `small <- head(mytwittersearch)`. If so, then you should post the output of `dput(small)`

Comment: Thank you BonedDust. the dput gives:structure(list(structure("#Budget cuts and #veterans preference may be keeping #Millennials out of the federal workforce http://t.co/sU7DCLm4H2 @WashingtonPost", Author = character(0), DateTimeStamp = structure(list(
    sec = 7.71148109436035, min = 34L, hour = 17L, mday = 3L, 
    mon = 0L, year = 115L, wday = 6L, yday = 2L, isdst = 0L), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), ............

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Error converting text to lowercase with tm\_map(..., tolower)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640188/error-converting-text-to-lowercase-with-tm-map-tolower)

Answer (score 10):

I use this code to get rid of the problem characters:

```
tweets$text <- sapply(tweets$text,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, but I wonder, does it get rid of emoji too or only alphabetic characters?

Comment: It removes all the emoji for me.

Comment: this solution works but only for latin characters. in case of frequent utf-8 conversion problems, the simplest code for conversion seems to be:

     `tweets$text <- iconv(tweets$text, "ASCII", "UTF-8", sub="byte")`

Answer (score 2):

A nice example on creating wordcloud from Twitter data is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/miningtwitter/questions/talking-about/wordclouds/wordcloud1). Using the example, and the code below, and passing the tolower parameter while creating the TermDocumentMatrix, I could create a Twitter wordcloud.

```
library(twitteR)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)


#Collect tweets containing 'new year'
tweets = searchTwitter("new year", n=50, lang="en")

#Extract text content of all the tweets
tweetTxt = sapply(tweets, function(x) x$getText())

#In tm package, the documents are managed by a structure called Corpus
myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(tweetTxt))

#Create a term-document matrix from a corpus
tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,stopwords = c("new", "year", stopwords("english")), removeNumbers = TRUE, tolower = TRUE))

#Convert as matrix
m = as.matrix(tdm)

#Get word counts in decreasing order
word_freqs = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing=TRUE) 

#Create data frame with words and their frequencies
dm = data.frame(word=names(word_freqs), freq=word_freqs)

#Plot wordcloud
wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, random.order=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Deb, I tried to run it, but get the same 'tolower' problem: Error in tolower(txt) : invalid input 'My New Year hope:
:
:
:
To get 

✨@Harry_Styles follow✨

It's my dream since 2013..

I love him from bottom of my heart❤️

please������������������' in 'utf8towcs'" Wish I could find a way to make it work, but there seems to be something wrong with the "tm" package.

Comment: I could successfully run the above code and get the wordcloud in Windows XP OS and RStudio.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried updating `tm` and using `stri_trans_tolower` from `stringi`?

```
library(twitteR)
library(tm)
library(stringi)
setup_twitter_oauth("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET")
mytwittersearch <- showStatus(551365749550227456) 
mytwittersearch_list <- mytwittersearch$getText()
mytwittersearch_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(mytwittersearch_list))

mytwittersearch_corpus <- tm_map(mytwittersearch_corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
# Error in FUN(content(x), ...) : 
#   invalid input 'í ½í±…í ¼í¾¯â¤í ¼í¾§í ¼í½œ "@comScore: Nearly half of #Millennials do at least some of their video viewing from a smartphone or tablet: http://t.co/56Fb78aTSC"' in 'utf8towcs'

mytwittersearch_corpus <- tm_map(mytwittersearch_corpus, content_transformer(stri_trans_tolower))
inspect(mytwittersearch_corpus)
# <<VCorpus (documents: 1, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>
#   
# [[1]]
# <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
# <ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B1><U+0085><ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00BE><U+00AF><U+2764><ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00BE><U+00A7><ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00BD><U+009C> "@comscore: nearly half of #millennials do at least some of their video viewing from a smartphone or tablet: http://t.co/56fb78atsc"
```

Comment: Stringi didn't help either :( It's strange because I still get the response: 
Error in match.fun(FUN) : could not find function "content_transformer". Could the content_transformer be found in any alternative package?

Comment: May I ask, is content_trasformer listed as part of your tm=package? When I search for it under my tm-package I get "no results found". I thought this was strange. It would be very interesting to compare if this comes up for others. Then I know it's something wrong with my tm package.

Comment: @AnneBoysen http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf#page=4 - yes it's part of `tm`.

Comment: Now, with tm package version 0.5-10, you can simply use : mytwittersearch_corpus <- tolower(mytwittersearch_corpus) . This should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions may have worked but not anymore in the newest versions of wordcloud and tm.

This problem almost made me crazy, but I found a solution and want to explain it the best I can to save anyone becoming desperate.

The function which is implicitly called by wordcloud and responsible for throwing the error

```
 Error in FUN(content(x), ...) : in 'utf8towcs'
```

is this one:

```
words.corpus <- tm_map(words.corpus, tolower)
```

which is a shortcut for

```
words.corpus <- tm_map(words.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
```

To provide a reproducible example, here's a function that embeds the solution:

```
plot_wordcloud <- function(words, max_words = 70, remove_words ="",
                           n_colors = 5, palette = "Set1")
{
    require(dplyr)
    require(wordcloud)
    require(RColorBrewer) # for brewer.pal()
    require(tm) # for tm_map()

    # Solution: remove all non-printable characters in UTF-8 with this line
    words <- iconv(words, "ASCII", "UTF-8", sub="byte")

    wc <- wordcloud(words=words.corpus, max.words=max_words,
                    random.order=FALSE,
                    colors = brewer.pal(n_colors, palette),
                    random.color = FALSE,
                    scale=c(5.5,.5), rot.per=0.35) %>% recordPlot
    return(wc)
}
```

Here's what failed:

I tried to convert the text BEFORE and AFTER creating the corpus with

```
words.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(words))
```

BEFORE:

Converting to UTF-8 on the text didn't work with:

```
words <- sapply(words, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte"))
```

nor

```
for (i in 1:length(words))
{
    Encoding(words[[i]])="UTF-8"
}
```

AFTER:

Converting to UTF-8 on the corpus didn't work with:

```
    words.corpus <- tm_map(words.corpus, removeWords, remove_words)
```

nor

```
    words.corpus <- tm_map(words.corpus, content_transformer(stringi::stri_trans_tolower))
```

nor

```
    words.corpus <- tm_map(words.corpus, function(x) iconv(x, to='UTF-8'))
```

nor

```
    words.corpus <- tm_map(words.corpus, enc2utf8)
```

nor

```
    words.corpus <- tm_map(words.corpus, tolower)
```

All these solutions may have worked at a certain point in time, so I don't want to discredit the authors. They may work some time in the future. But why they didn't work is almost impossible to say because there were good reasons why they were supposed to work.
Anyway, just remember to convert the text before creating the corpus with:

```
    words <- iconv(words, "ASCII", "UTF-8", sub="byte")
```

Disclaimer:
I got the solution with more detailed explanation here:
http://www.textasdata.com/2015/02/encoding-headaches-emoticons-and-rs-handling-of-utf-816/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with updating my RStudio and packages. This seemed to solve the tolower/ content_transformer issues. I read somewhere that the last tm-package had some issues with tm_map, so maybe that was the problem. In any case, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(tolower), mc.cores=1)
```

use

```
corp <- tm_map(corp, tolower, mc.cores=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

While using code similar to that above and working on a word cloud shiny app which ran fine on my own pc, but didn't work either on amazon aws or shiny apps.io, I discovered that text with 'accents',e.g. santé in it didn't upload well as csv files to the cloud. I found a solution by saving the files as .txt files and in utf-8 using notepad and re-writing my code to allow for the fact that the files were no longer csv but txt. My versions of R was 3.2.1 and Rstudio was Version 0.99.465

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, I had the same problem in a different context (nothing to do with tm or Twitter). For me, the solution was `iconv(x, "latin1", "UTF-8")`, even though `Encoding()` told me it was already UTF-8.