# How to use tm package for text analytics in Hebrew or Arabic

Tags: r, text, tm

I would like to use tm package for Hebrew or Arabic text analysis. I tried several methods to see if tm will be able to process some words but i ran into an error, Is there a way to solve this issue?

```
 text  <- "הנוסעים חיכו זמן רב לנסיעה"
 Encoding(text)
#[1] "unknown"
 Encoding(text)  <- "UTF-8"
 ap.corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(text)))
 ap.corpus <- tm_map(ap.corpus, removePunctuation)
 ap.corpus <- tm_map(ap.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
Error in FUN(content(x), ...) : 
  invalid input 'הנוסעים חיכו זמן רב לנסיעה' in 'utf8towcs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, we need to add this encoding method:

```
iconv(text, "ISO-8859-8", "UTF-8")[1]
```

Instead of using : `Encoding(text)  <- "UTF-8"`

Answer (score 1):

From the [tm vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf):

> The second argument `readerControl` of the corpus constructor has to be
>   a list with the named components reader and language. (...) Finally, the
>   second component `language` sets the texts’ language (preferably using
>   ISO 639-2 codes).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes), the ISO 639-2 code for Arabic is `ara` and for Hebrew `heb`. So maybe try this:

```
 ap.corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(text), readerControl = list(language = "heb")))
```

Edit: Glad you found the answer. When the wrong encoding is used this error comes up:

- [R tm package invalid input in 'utf8towcs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637278/r-tm-package-invalid-input-in-utf8towcs)
- [FUN-error after running 'tolower' while making Twitter wordcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756693/fun-error-after-running-tolower-while-making-twitter-wordcloud)

Comment: Hi @Hoju, I got:
Error in DataframeSource(data.frame(text), readerControl = list(language = "heb")) : 
  unused argument (readerControl = list(language = "heb"))